# how to turn on vpn in ios app ? ( public api )

Tags: ios, vpn

there are many kind of app in appstore that use vpn on demand.
some application like hotspotshield when you open the app, it can turn vpn on even if vpn on demand is off.
is there any public api for turning vpn on in app, like hotspotshield ?

Answer (score 0):

even astrill is an app available for ios ([iPhone VPN connect app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564263/iphone-vpn-connect-app)).. it provides a toggle to switch vpn on and off from the app directly... so my guess is it used some third party api..

right now.. there is no public api available to toggle vpn from an app..

urlscheme could have been used to atleast open vpn setting from ur app .. but even that was deprecated.. so no chance for now

Answer (score 0):

Now it's possible, but only with IPSec and IKEv2 protocols. See this great example https://github.com/lexrus/VPNOn